# How do you extend the wires from the arduino board to both fsr sensors to be placed on both chairs (one for each)

Tags: arduino-uno

I’m trying to figure out how to extend the wires for both force sensitive resistors so that it could be place on each chair, one sensor on one chair and the other sensor on the other chair

This is how this was originally connected

[image]

So what would be the best way to extend both cables to place both sensors on each chair

Comment: why can't you use longer wires? Are there capacitance or noise problems?

Answer (score 1):

In ADC sampling there will always be noise.  Longer cables may increase that noise.  Sensors with lower resistance tend have less noise.  For these reasons it would be better to start from a schematic, part numbers and / or specifications rather than a picture.

There are a number of ways to reduce noise.  Hardware solutions include twisted pair and shielded cables.  Software solutions include averaging multiple samples and removing outliers.

If all you are asking is if you can use longer cables, the answer is yes as long as you can tolerate the or compensate for additional noise if any.

Answer (score 1):

In order to extend the wires you will need:

- [Crimp Connector Housing](http://core-electronics.com.au/0-1-2-54mm-crimp-connector-housing-1x1-pin-25-pack.html)
- [Female Crimp Pins](http://core-electronics.com.au/female-crimp-pins-for-0-1-housings-100-pack.html)
- [Male Crimp Pins](http://core-electronics.com.au/male-crimp-pins-for-0-1-housings-100-pack.html)
- [Stranded Wire: 30 AWG](http://core-electronics.com.au/stranded-wire-red-30-awg-100-feet.html)

and if you want to do a better job than bread board then you can use a [Strip board](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/5Pcs-Double-Side-5x7cm-Printed-Circuit-PCB-Vero-Prototyping-Track-Strip-Board-SY-/252324587520?hash=item3abfb7a800:g:9EIAAOSwHgVW7ENM) to solder your resistors on and some [headers](http://core-electronics.com.au/10-pcs-40-pin-headers-straight.html) to connect your wires.

You should not get any noise in ideal situation.

I don't know where you from so I just posted the links to the store I usually buy from. you can find these items on ebay or similar. Plus you will need a [crimping tool](http://core-electronics.com.au/crimping-tool-0-08-0-5-mm-capacity-20-28-awg.html) as well.